# Round up SYSDATE just but its HOUR. SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, time, sysdate

Any ideas how to round up SYSDATE.

For example, sysdate right now is `11.31`, and i want it to round up to `12.00`, but i expect the output to be just `12`, and if the Sysdate is `11.29`, the output is `11`.

Thanks

Comment: so you want to round up to the next hour -- only when you are pas 30 mins?

Comment: @Hogan that's right. round up after the 30th minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ROUND((SYSDATE-TRUNC(SYSDATE))*24)
```

Explanation: `TRUNC` without 2nd parameter makes the 00:00:00 time of the current date. By subtraction we get the difference (in days), then scale it to hours and round.

Comment: @MarioAlexander 23:31 will produce 24 instead of 00.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROUND` function and after that `TO_CHAR`.

```
select to_char(round(to_date('11:31','hh24:mi'), 'HH'), 'HH24') from dual

-> 12

select to_char(round(to_date('11:29','hh24:mi'), 'HH'), 'HH24') from dual

-> 11
```